# auto generate custom id with sql

Tags: mysql, auto-generate

I am relatively new to sql and databases and would like some help in the following topic.
I have the following table: (junior male -> jm, junior female -> jf, adult male -> am, adult female-> af)

```
id    code     name    
1     jm       john       
2     am       patrick    
3     af       jane       
4     jm       peter      
5     jm       derrick    
6     af       mary       
7     jf       jessica
```

and would like to create a field inside the table as a reference which is made up of the code and autoincrement digits in this way:

```
id      code     name     reference

1     jm       john       jm001

2     am       patrick    am001

3     af       jane       af001

4     jm       peter      jm002

5     jm       derrick    jm003

6     af       mary       af002

7     jf       jessica    jf001
```

can anyone give me some tips on how to do this? Thank you

Comment: Why? You can always calculate this `reference` when needed from the `id` and `code` columns? For the `id` you would need an `identity` or `auto increment` column (terminology varies)

Comment: You can use Computed column, for this we may know the DBMS you are using

Comment: @MartinSmith I need to store it as a value inside the database so that it will be a searchable field, not calculate it whenever I need it. what do you suggest?

Comment: @rbc089 - You still don't really as your application could just strip out the first 2 characters as the code and the remainder as the `id` and use them as separate parameters in the search. But I have no idea what type of application you are building, what RDBMS you are using so can't suggest anything specific.

Comment: @MartinSMith but in that way you can't get jm002 like in the example but instead you'll get jm004. I'm using mySQL as RDBMS.

Comment: Ah right didn't notice that. That makes the requirement even worse unless your RDBMS has specific support for it. If possible get the requirement changed. Why is it important that the numbers are sequential? It makes `inserts` more complicated and less performant (have to get next value to use, have to consider concurrency)

Comment: the reason is that im dealing with a large database (about 40000 records inside this particular table), and would like the reference to be as simple as possible, in such a way that I would not be required to add more numbers if more records are added. for example if there is the record (id 2, code jm, name john, reference jm0002) and the record (id 302, code jm, name peter) and no junior male in between, then ids jm 0003 - jm0301 would be "lost". I'm not sure if I made my view clear, apologies if I got you confused

Comment: I still don't understand why do you need sequential numbers. But if you want, you can create 4 tables jm(id,name), am(id,name), af(id, name) and jf(id, name).

Comment: @Karolis i'll guess I'll have to settle for concatenation of code and id. The problem now is the leading zeros. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: till now I have something like this in mind: 

UPDATE test_users
SET reference=CONCAT(test_users.code,test_users.id)

Comment: @rbc089 LPAD: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Answer (score 1):

First, ask yourself "Why?" as in Martin's comment.  If you have a good answer to this question, then a sequence for each type is probably what you are looking for.  For example in Oracle:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE jm_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE;
CREATE SEQUENCE jf_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE;
CREATE SEQUENCE am_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE;
CREATE SEQUENCE af_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE;
```

Then, you can use these when you enter the specific types.  For example, to enter a junior male, you'd use:

```
Insert into table_name 
  values (id_seq.nextVal, 'jm', 'Bart', 'jm' || jm_seq.nextVal);
```

Also, this will not give you leading zeros as in your example, so look into formatting your number if that is needed.

Comment: does this also apply to mysql?

Comment: @rbc089:  Yes, though you'll have to change up the syntax for sequence creation, sequence use, and string concatenation.

Comment: @Briguy37 Nope. MySQL does not have sequences. MySQL uses a little different concept for automatic id generation.

Comment: @rbc089:  Sorry for misleading you about sequences in MySQL.  It does look like you can [emulate them](http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/), but I see that you have already have an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this following Code in-order to arrive to your desired result... Cheers...

```
drop table if exists Custom_id_Dynamic;
create table Custom_id_Dynamic (id int primary key auto_increment , Code varchar(20), 
Name varchar(20), Reference varchar(20));


drop procedure if exists Dynamic_id;

set @index:=0;
set @jm:=0;
set @unknown:=0;
set @am:=0;
set @af:=0;
set @jf:=0;

delimiter $$

create procedure Dynamic_id(
in code_new varchar(20), in name_new varchar(20)
)

begin
set code_new=lower(code_new);
if code_new='jm' then set @jm:=@jm+1, @index:=@jm;
elseif code_new='am' then set @am:=@am+1, @index:=@am;
elseif code_new='af' then set @af:=@af+1, @index:=@af;
elseif code_new='jf' then set @jf:=@jf+1, @index:=@jf;
else set @unknown:=@unknown+1, @index:=@unknown;
end if;
insert into Custom_id_Dynamic (Code, Name, Reference) 
values (code_new, name_new, concat(code_new, lpad(@index,3,0)));
end;



call Dynamic_id('jm','john');
call Dynamic_id('am','patrick');
call Dynamic_id('af','jane');
call Dynamic_id('jm','peter');
call Dynamic_id('jm','derrick');
call Dynamic_id('af','mary');
call Dynamic_id('jf','jessica');


select * from Custom_id_Dynamic;
```